# Get the filename of a file that was created through ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory()

Tags: c#

```
string zipPath = @"D:\books\"+fileinfo.DccFileName;
string extractPath = @"D:\books";
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

This is a simple piece of code that does exactly what i want it to do: Gets a zip file from d:\books and unzips it into the same directory. Is there any way i can read the filename of the newly created file (considering that there is only one file in the .zip archive). I would prefer a solution that does not involve reading changes in the directory since other files might be created in it at the same time of the unzip.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `extractPath + nameOfFileInsideZip`?

Comment: If there's only one archive entry, why are you using `ExtractToDirectory()`? I mean, it's not hard to infer the resulting file name from the entry name (which could include directory components), but since you have to navigate the archive's entry list to do that anyway, why not just extract the archive entry directly, with your own code creating the file name (which then you'd already have in hand instead of trying to infer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct the path by inspecting the archive

```
var intentedPath = string.Empty;
//open archive
using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath)) {
    //since there is only one entry grab the first
    var entry = archive.Entries.First();
    //the relative path of the entry in the zip archive
    var fileName = entry.FullName;
    //intended path once extracted would be
    intentedPath = Path.Combine(extractPath, fileName);
}
```